# sticky footer issue - empty space suddenly showing under footer

Tags: css, footer, sticky-footer

I created a website for a friend with a css sticky footer.

It is supposed to look like here: http://abchealth.info/doc-mike-special/test2/

It worked fine until I added the very last segment of the long sales page at http://abchealth.info/doc-mike-special/, then suddenly the footer layout got messed up and there's suddenly a whole lot of empty space under the footer :(

I can't figure out why, being an amateur myself...can anyone help??

To save time I extracted the html and css that seems most likely relevant, hop this helps:

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="mastercontainer">
</div>

<div id="footerclear">
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
div#wrap {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
padding-bottom: 605px;
}
div#mastercontainer {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
div#footerclear {
}
div#footer {
position: relative;
margin-top: -570px;
height: 570px;
clear: both;
background-image: url(http://abchealth.info/images/footer-bg.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any (beginner-friendly) help, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

1. remove the width 100% in `<div id="main">` in main.css line no 35 so the vertical scroll will remove

in your demo

[image]

after make it correct result

> [image]